# Error deleting files with FineUploader

Tags: javascript, file-io, fine-uploader

I am uploading several files with FineUploader and I have a cancel button to stop the upload process and delete all the files that have been uploaded. When I click on "Delete" in each file it works fine, but since some time ago (not sure if it was with the update to 3.9 or before that) I am getting a blank alert and a "Delete Failed" message, but the files are deleted from the server so the Servlet is working fine.

My code to delete the files is something like this:

```
function clearFiles() {
    var array = document.getElementsByClassName("qq-upload-delete");
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].style="display: inline;";
        array[i].click();
    }
}
```

I am guessing if the problem could be being trying to delete the files without waiting to the confirmation message (so I am deleting the next one before I get the response from the previous one) or something else, but I can't explain the blank alert. I didn't find any documentation or example about this. Any ideas?

**Console Log:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined. 
Uncaught Error: Element not found drop. 
[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] DELETE request for 0 has failed - response code 0 
[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Delete request for 'test File.pdf' has failed. id: test File.pdf, fileName: Delete request failed with response code 0, reason: [Object XMLHttpRequest]
```

**Server code:**

```
public void doDelete(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String uuid = req.getPathInfo().replaceAll("/", "");
    FileUtils.deleteUploadedFile(uuid);
    resp.setStatus(successResponseCode);
}
```

**FineUploader definition**

```
myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#file-uploader')[0],
    multiple: false,
    autoUpload: true,
    deleteFile: {enabled: true, forceConfirm: false, endpoint: '/upload-portlet/fineupload/receiver'},
...
});

imageUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#image-uploader')[0],
    multiple: false,
    autoUpload: true,
    deleteFile: {enabled: true, forceConfirm: false, endpoint: '/upload-portlet/fineupload/receiver'},
...
});
```

**New clearFiles method**

```
function clearFiles() {
    if (myUploader && myUploader.getUploads()) {
        var array = myUploader.getUploads();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            myUploader.deleteFile(array[i].id);
        }
    }
    if (imageUploader && imageUploader.getUploads()) {
        var array = imageUploader.getUploads();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            imageUploader .deleteFile(array[i].id);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't works for imageUploader but it does for myUploader. Any idea why?

Comment: Why are you doing this again, instead of simply calling the deleteFile API method?  Also, list all of your client-side code and your console log messages.

Comment: By requirements, I have two instances of fineuploader in the same jsp. Should I use something like $('#id').fineUploader('deleteFile', id);?

Comment: Yes.  Also, please post your client-side code and the contents of the javascript console so we can further assist.

Comment: JS Console: Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined. Uncaught Error: Element not found drop. [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] DELETE request for 0 has failed - response code 0 [FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Delete request for 'test File.pdf' has failed. id: test File.pdf, fileName: Delete request failed with response code 0, reason: [Object XMLHttpRequest]

Comment: Fine Uploader doesn't use Modernizr, so that is an error elsewhere in your code.  Also, I'm looking for console log messages that exist when you reproduce the issue you are asking about here.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing. The first two messages are before I execute my code, so I guess something is wrong elsewhere. It is weird that the file name is different to the actual file name - I am using the id and the file name concatenated in the server (something like ab45cc3c-8e8a-4da3-98d4-35910944eea2_test File.pdf)

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is at this point.

Comment: Let me try with the API. what should the id be? My file name is "test File.pdf", the actual file name in the server is "ab45cc3c-8e8a-4da3-98d4-35910944eea2_test File.pdf" and the html id is something else.

Comment: The ID is the same ID reported by Fine Uploader in event handlers.  Fine Uploader assigns a numerical ID for each file that is unique for that session only.

Comment: What are you seeing in the network tab of Chrome when this happens?  Post the request and associated response data.

Comment: In red, Method: DELETE, Status: (Canceled), Type: Pending, Initiator: fineuploader-3.9.0-3.min.js:17 Script, Size (Content): 13B (0B),Time (Latency):10 ms(-)

Comment: Something on your page or server is interfering with the request/response then.

Comment: But why if I click over the Delete option it works and I don't get any error? Why it is showing the error message but the servlet is deleting the file? I will test with the API and let you know.

Comment: I am defining each uploader with myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({element: $('#file-uploader')[0], ... How can I call the deleteFile method?

Comment: myUploader.deleteFile(...)

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I am getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined ". I have this code: var id = $(document.getElementById('uuid')).val(); alert('id: '+id); myUploader.deleteFile(id); where id is File id (the automatic generated id, something like ab45cc3c-8e8a-4da3-98d4-35910944eea2)

Comment: You are passing in the UUID.  That method requires you pass in the ID.

Comment: How can I get the ID?

Comment: In your specific case, see the `getUploads` method at http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/statistics-and-status-updates.html.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Anyway, I guessed that it would be 0 (I am only uploading 1 file in this case), but I still am getting the Delete Failed message.

Comment: Then your server is not returning a proper response, or something is interfering with the response/request, as stated above.

Comment: I modified my original clearFiles by var array = myUploader.getUploads();
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  myUploader.deleteFile(array[i].id);
 } but I have the same behavior as before. I will try to figure it out what it is. Is it possible to have a deleteAllFiles function that does this?

Comment: I found a problem in my onDeleteComplete, I think it should work now but as I have two uploaders in the same jsp (myUploader = new qq.FineUploader... and imageUploader = new qq.FineUploader...), the first uploader's file are removed but I get an error in the second one (object has not getUploads). It is pretty weird. Could it be that both uploaders are being mixed so the elements are deleted (so when I try to remove the second file in imageUploader it is not found) but not the files in the server?

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit.  Your original question has been answered.  If you have additional issues, please open up a new question.  Avoid inserting additional issues into your original question.  I would recommend deleting this question entirely, actually, since it is a bit confusing for onlookers, myself included. Keep in mind that Stack overflow is a Q&A site, and not a forum.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ray, I will keep in mind what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in onDeleteComplete that affected the functionality. Fixing that, the original clearFiles worked.

Thank you very much to the FineUploader team for the help!!

Comment: You should post your original code above, and your working code below for others to learn from :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark. I always try to post as much code as I can, but in this case the jsp is too complicated so it is better to keep it simple. Will try to create something useful for the related one :)

Comment: > There was a problem in onDeleteComplete that affected the functionality. -- you could at least post your before and after onDeleteComplete function. I agree that the JSP would be mostly useless to others.

Comment: :) The onDeleteComplete is executed every time the delete is done. The behavior I created in that method was different if I was removing one file or more than one. As the objective was to remove all files and close the window, it didn't matter what happens with everything else (hidden variables, etc.). So to avoid conflicts I added a big if (!closing) { //do whatever} inside that method, and update the closing=true before executing clearFiles. Hope it helps.